# Timer to begin on the start date entered by user

Tags: javascript, html, input, timer

I have a working timer but the idea is that the timer does not start until the date and time the user enters comes. for example,
startdate: 1/15/2021 time: 1:15pm
enddate: 1/15/2021 time: 1:18pm
if today is the 14th and I entered this information today (14th), the timer shouldn't start until the 15th at exactly 1:15 pm.
I used the setTimeout function where I passed in the start

```js
function myfunction(){

// Set the date we're counting down to

var enddate= document.getElementById("end_date").value;
var startdate = document.getElementById("start_date").value;

if(startdate == '' || enddate == ''){
return
}

enddate = new Date(enddate)
startdate = new Date(startdate)
var distance = enddate - startdate;



// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get start date and time
  //var startdate = document.getElementById("start_date").innerHTML;
    
  // Find the distance between startdate and the end date
  //var distance = enddate - startdate;
 // console.log(distance)
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  
  distance = distance - 1000;
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }

   if (minutes == 20) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Heart rate and blood pressure will drop";}
}, 1000);

}

var y = setTimeout(function(){
alert("tryout starts now")
}, startdate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>




<input type="datetime-local" id="start_date"  onchange='myfunction()' placeholder="Start Date" />
 - 
<input type="datetime-local" id="end_date" onchange='myfunction()' placeholder="End Date" />
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

date to indicate that that's when it should start but it's not working. Any other approach/idea will be welcomed.

Comment: there are a few issues here. One would be the function is only executed when the user invokes the function, after the function completes there is nothing checking again to see if the timer should start, (this should be async as well), You need to store the start and end time in cookie/session and create a function to check the stored data of the cookie/session to see if it should start the timer.